# Find the basis of a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the basis of a linear subspace in Rn which consists of all n-dimensional vectors with coordinates (a,b,a,...,b).

I do not know how to solve these kind of problems when the coordinates are some kind of variables. My instinct tells me its dimension is 2 and the basis is kinda like this: (1,0,1,...0) and (0,1,0,...1), but I just can't prove it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  To prove it, use the definition of a basis

Comment: I apologize, what I really meant was how to get to the solution

Comment: @Howard Can you write a vector $(a, b, a, \ldots , b)$ of the form $\alpha_{1} (1, 0, 1, \ldots , 0) + \alpha_{2} (0, 1, 0, \ldots 1)$ for suitably chosen real numbers $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$? This should answer most of your question.

Answer (score 1):

We claim that $B_1 = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$ is a basis. To show this, we first verify that the vectors in $B_1$ are linearly independent. This is easy to see: if you row-reduce $\begin{pmatrix} v_1 & v_2 \end{pmatrix}$, you get

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

which has a pivot in each column. Then, we verify that $\text{Span} B_1$ is equal to the subspace. That $\text{Span} B_1$ is contained in the subspace is easy to see: both elements of $B_1$ are contained in the subspace. To check that the subspace is contained in $\text{Span} B_1$, row-reduce the system $\begin{pmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & w \end{pmatrix}$ to get

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 1 & b \\ 1 & 0 & a \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & 0 & a \end{pmatrix} \longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

which is consistent, since there is no pivot in the augmented column.